# MOSS 2007 Document Library - choice column not displaying selected value

Tags: sharepoint, moss, document-library

I have something funky going on with MOSS & was wondering if anyone out there has seen anything like it:

I have a document library in MOSS that has several custom columns added to it.  I have a column of type choice.  For one document in the library (a word document), the selected value does not get displayed for the one column - all of the other columns are fine & the other 60 documents in the folder display the selected values correctly.  When I edit the properties of the document, the value of the column is defaulted to blank, I can change it to another value & save it. However the new value doesn't get displayed in the list view, nor does it show up if I edit the properties again.

If, I open the document in word & view the Document Information Panel it displayes the value that I had selected & saved for the column.  However, the column is being displayed as a text box & not a drop down.  The value still does not get displayed in the list view  or properties view after a save.

Has anyone seen behaviour like this before?

Answer (score 2):

My first guess is a name collision between your custom column and the columns that ship with SharePoint out of the box.  What is the column name that is causing the problem?

I have seen situations like this when there are documents in a library, and then columns are added.  The existing information does not get updated properly.

Comment: You know what, that's most likely the case.  The column name is Subject.  I'm sure that that must be an OOTB column name.

Answer (score 1):

If you reupload the document as a second content, does this happends again ?

If yes, you may check advanced properties of the document before uploadind it. There may be some data in it that SharePoint try to use when importing the file. It may explain that you don't have the issue when you copy/paste only the content.

Comment: Yes, I made a copy of the file & uploaded it again and it resulted in the same behaviour.

It's something particular to the file. I can make a new file & copy the content of the old file into it & it works fine.

So, it's not a show stopper, but still very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Along a similar line, it could be that the problem doc has a Word metadata field named subject, and MOSS is doing its property promotion thing to mess up your field. If so, clearing the Word metadata might fix it.